# limit text with jquery

Tags: jquery, text

I'm trying to limit my descriptions texts in a list view to an amount number of charachters with the option to toggle down the rest of it on click. Limiting the text is not a problem it works with the following code snippet http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/G42dR/5/

```
$("p").each(function(i) {
    len = $(this).text().length;
    if (len > 150) {
        $(this).text($(this).html().substr(0, 150));
    }
});
```

How could add the dropdown event to it?

Comment: clicking on Read More should toggle down the rest of the text

Comment: Why oh why in the world would you do $(this).text($(this).html())? You're going to get lots of nice looking markup in your descriptions! Also, you should definitely store some variables in there because typing $(this) every time is pretty much a useless bottleneck. To answer your question, when you trim the descriptions, store the original description on the element with .data() and then retrieve it during the event to display the full description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to wrap the "preview" portion and the remaining portion of your text in separate spans. Then, you could add a link that toggles whether the span containing the remaining portion of the text is hidden or displayed:

```
$(this).html("<span>" + $(this).text().substr(0,150) + "</span><span style='display:none'>" + $(this).text().substr(150) + "</span>");

var link = $("<a href='#' class='more'>More..</a>");
$(this).append(link);
$(link).click(function(){
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    $(this).html($(this).html()=="More.."?"Less":"More..");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G42dR/9/

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you:

```
            $('p').each(function(){
                if($(this).text().length > 150){
                    $(this).attr('data-text', $(this).text());
                    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0, 150));
                    $(this).after($('<a onclick="$(this).prev().text($(this).prev().attr(\'data-text\')); $(this).remove();"> Read more...</a>'));
                }
            });
```