# How can i set text field limit to 500 bytes?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, byte, character-limit

I have one text field and I want to limit its max enter **character** limit to 500 **bytes**.
How is it possible? May be I should use jQuery for that. But I don't know how.
Any best example?
In my question, I want to limit character limit to 500 Bytes, which is different than 500 character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949716/limit-html-text-input-to-a-particular-number-of-bytes

Comment: [if you meant textarea in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533053/textarea-character-limit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [limit text with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449994/limit-text-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript's [Blob.size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/size) you can get the number of bytes from a string like this:

```js
document
  .getElementById('str')
  .addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const bytes = new Blob([e.target.value]).size
    // your logic...

    console.clear()
    console.log(`${bytes} bytes`)      
  })
```

```html
<input type="text" id="str">
```

Comment: So that means, if i simply limit text field size to 500, will it be equivalent to limiting to 500 bytes?

Comment: Yes, the total bytes of the text in the input.. Now you can implement your logic to notify the end user

Comment: Also, what if i want to warn user on reaching max character limit?